# ms sql server 2005 sa account can not access the database i created while the system databse is ok

Tags: sql-server, sa

Just like the title said. I try to write a tutorial to show how to communicate with the ms sql server.

And I can communicate with the system database such like master and model.
But while I create a database manually, I can't access the database. All I got is: can't open the request database.

```
       String driverName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
       String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433; DatabaseName=ddf"; //ddf is what I created.
       String userName = "sa";
       String userPwd = "123456";
       Class.forName(driverName);
   dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, userPwd);
   System.out.println("Connection Successful!"); 
   Statement stmt = dbConn.createStatement();
   String sql = "select * from ddf..ff";
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
   while(rs.next()){
       System.out.println(rs.getRow());
   }
   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
   dbConn.close();
```

Comment: and if you connect to master and query ddf.dbo.ff ?

Comment: Yeah. I can connect to the master, and query the data from it. But what frake me out is i can't access the custom database table.

Comment: btw, the error code is 4060

Comment: my question was: can you query the custom database table when being connected to the master database ?

Comment: How did you create the database?  What happens when you connect with SQL Server Management Studio as user sa?  Has the model database been modified in any way?